# React, al editar código en un useEffect se me borra la información de mi app almacenada en localStorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, useeffect

Hola que tal me está pasando algo realmente curioso y no sé a que se debe, yo estoy haciendo un todolist, y las notas que el usuario va generando dinámicamente, se almacenan en el localStorage, esto lo hago con el siguiente código :
En el componente `App.js`

```
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
   const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false); //cambia el template de la app
   //Se encarga de mostrar la nota para escribir 
   const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true); //eslint-disable-line
  useEffect(() => {
    const saveNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes-data'));
    if (saveNotes){
      setNotes(saveNotes);
    }
    
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes-data', JSON.stringify(notes))
  },[notes])

const addNote = (inputText, text) => { //ese text, es el texto úncamente del textArea
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      title: inputText,
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleString()
      
    }
    const newNotes = [newNote, ...notes];
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }
```

Siguiendo en el componente `App.js` el valor que es un array que tiene `notes` lo paso como prop a través de un filtrado, a otro componente, `<Pagination  data={filterNotes} />`.

```
const filterNotes = notes.filter((noteText) => noteText.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText));
  
  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''}>

    <div className="container">
      <Header 
        handleToggleTheme={setDarkMode}
      />
      <Search 
        handleSearchNote={setSearchText}
        setShowNote={setShowNote}
        />
      <Pagination 
        data={filterNotes} 
        handleAddNote={addNote}
        handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
        searchText={searchText}
        />
    </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Pues bien en mi componente `Pagination`, necesito hacer un useEffect con el siguiente código:

```
const Pagination = (props) => {

 const { data, handleAddNote, handleDeleteNote } = props;
  // We start with an empty list of items.
 const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]);
 const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  // Here we use item offsets; we could also use page offsets
  // following the API or data you're working with.
 const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
 const itemsPerPage = 9;

 useEffect(()=>{
    setItemOffset(0)
  },[data])

  return (
    <>
      <NoteList 
      
        notes={currentItems}
        handleAddNote={handleAddNote}
        handleDeleteNote={handleDeleteNote}
      />
    //Resto de código
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Si intento hacer cambios en el componente Pagination, dentro del useEffect que veis, no sé que le ocurre a la aplicación que los datos almacenados previamente en localStorage se borran todos, actualmente las notas son de testeo y su contenido no es importante, pero no me da seguridad, imaginar que tengo notas que no quiero borrar, y al hacer un cambio de código se borra todo..
¿Alguien sabe que puede estar ocurriendo? ¿Hay alguna forma de recuperar las notas borradas previamente almacenadas en localStorage?

Cuando se borran las notas, inspeccionando con el developer tools, veo que la variable notes-data lo que tiene es un array vacío [].

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que aquí estas haciendo el "set" de "notes" a un array vacío

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
```

y tu valor inicial debería ser el localStorage

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes-data')) || "[]" );
```

Además toma en cuenta que el local storage solo guarda strings no arrays

Comment: Con el useEffect que tengo en pagination, que hará su función cuando data se renderice, en ningún momento reseteo setNotes a un array vacío, por eso me extraña mucho el problema, gracias por tu respuesta ^^